# iOS TimeZone get three letter abbreviation

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nstimezone

I need to get three/four letter abbreviation for the country called **'Africa/Nairobi'**, I have tried using

`print(TimeZone(abbreviation: "SAST")?.identifier)` from the `NSTimeZone.abbreviationDictionary`, results `nil`.

How to get the three/four letter abbreviations for this country **'Africa/Nairobi'**. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a full standard localized name of timezone by the following method.

```
let timezone:TimeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "Africa/Nairobi") ?? TimeZone.current
print(timezone.localizedName(for: .generic, locale: .autoupdatingCurrent))
print(timezone.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: .autoupdatingCurrent))
```

Will give you following output

> Optional("East Africa Time")
>
> Optional("East Africa Time")

I think now you get easily get EAT form East Africa Time by spliting and combining string

```
let fullName = timezone.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: .autoupdatingCurrent) ?? ""
var result = ""
fullName.enumerateSubstrings(in: fullName.startIndex..<fullName.endIndex, options: .byWords) { (substring, _, _, _) in
    if let substring = substring { result += substring.prefix(1) }
}
print(result)
```

Will give you out put

> EAT